# AdvancedDataGrid problem with programmatically adding a column

Tags: apache-flex

I have a Problem with adding columns programmatically to a AdvancedDataGrid. The code:

```
var cols:Array = thisDataGrid.columns;
cols.push(dgc);
thisDataGrid.columns = cols;
```

does create a column, adds it to the cols array, bot the last code line has no effect. The cols wont be found in the thisDataGrid.columns property...

What could be the problem? I'm working with a test license, and on the advanceddatagrid the watermark shows up. Could this be a problem?

Thanks for help!

Markus

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and resolved it by making sure that I add my ADG object into an active visual component. In my case, I just made a call to this.addElement( adg ) (or this.addChild() ) after updating the adg.column property.

It seems like the adg properties will only update when the adg is "attached" to an active visual component. I havn't taken the time to really look into the cause of this behaviour though.

Answer (score 0):

try doing invalidateProperties() and invalidateDisplayList() on grid